# Installation of Perl library Net version > 0.66

Tags: perl, ubuntu, download, package

I have installed INetSim on Ubuntu and when I start it, I get the following message:

```
 The installed version 0.65 of Perl library Net::DNS is broken. 
 Please upgrade to version 0.66 or later.
```

So, I use Ubuntu for the first time. I googled for that package but I am not sure which command to type in the terminal. 
Can somebody tell me the correct lines that I can type into the terminal ?

EDIT:
when I run the 'cpan' - command, then I get the following:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It depends on your Perl installation. Try `cpan Net::DNS`

Comment: Did this not work for you?

Comment: I got the message: "mkdir /root/.cpan: Permission denied at /usr/share/perl/5.10/CPAN/FTP.pm line 501"

Comment: Sorry, that should be `sudo cpan Net::DNS`

Comment: No, problem. Now, I have a lot of "Warning: no successful downloading"-messages. And at the end, it says: "Could not fetch authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"

Comment: That's odd. Does it give any clue about *why* the download failed? Perhaps you could edit your question and add the log.

Comment: @Borodin: Yes, your advice worked!!! The problem for the odd messages above was that I had no available network connection at the time when I wrote your recommended command. Now, after getting network connection, it worked and inetsim does not show the "dns-fail"-message. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, if you're not using CPAN, try `sudo apt-get install libnet-dns-perl` to upgrade your library.  I just tried it on my own machine and it installed version 0.66.

Comment: after your recommended command, it says: "libnet is already the newest version". But the message mentioned in my first post is still there.